# HP Probook 450 G3 Boot Failure

Tags: boot, laptop

Computer doesn't boot, the screen stays black even though it has power.

Doesn't boot to BIOS cooling fan comes on and stays on high.

Caps lock and num lock blinking in sets of three total of 5x.

Airplane mode stuck on, volume mute button light too.

Power button will not allow sleep either only will power down by holding in button for 5 seconds.

Comment: As Ive said I have tried clearing the Cache I tried using Umbuntu LTS and Rufus ..I put those two programs onto my external harddrive but they are not booting me up either

Comment: I have power And the cooling Fan is running on high as the caps lock and the num. lock blink white lights only no beeps series of three blinks 5x only then no blinks after that

Answer (score 3):

#### Caps lock and num lock blinking in sets of three

Contact support for repair due to graphics or video failure.

> Specific patterns of long and short blinks along with long and short
>   beeps (where applicable) identify errors during the startup process.
>   Newer computers have two-part blink sequences with different color
>   lights to indicate specific errors. The LED blink/beep sequence near
>   Caps Lock and Number Lock keys indicates the type of error:
>
> - The red Caps Lock LED blinks are long.
> - The white Caps Lock LED blinks are short. For example, ‘3.5’ indicates 3 long red blinks and 5 short white blinks.
> - On systems that do not have a dual-color LED, both long and short blinks are white.
> - Some systems do not have a speaker and do not beep.
>
> ...
>
> [image]

Source [HP Notebook PCs - Computer Does Not Start and Emits an LED or Beep Code | HP® Customer Support](https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c01732674)

Comment: Already went there they have what appears to be a bot answering questions and gives you a different name everytime you log in and out of thier system

Comment: is there a reset from complete shutdown to powering on the laptop my screen is not completely powerless i can see a slight variation in color change ,..almost like a greyish black then completely black on power down

Comment: @ebrossbluesman3ebrossbluesman there is not a reset. Your computer is telling you there is a hardware failure. Get it repaired or replace it.